# Design an algorithm to input 3 numbers and then output the highest in little man computing

Tags: algorithm, little-man-computer

I can program it to output the highest of 2 numbers but am stuck on how to output the highest of 3 numbers input. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Let say you have variables `A`, `B` and `C`. And there's an additional variable to hold the max value: `D`. Compare `A` and `B` to find the max value and store it into `D`. Then compare `D` and `C` to find the max value.

Answer (score 3):

In words:

```
read input into mailboxes M0, M1, M2
if M1 > M2
    store M1 into M2
if M0 > M2
    store M0 into M2
output M2
```

In little man computer assembler:

```
    INP
    STA M0
    INP
    STA M1
    INP
    STA M2

    SUB M1
    BRP J1
    LDA M1
    STA M2
J1  LDA M2
    SUB M0
    BRP J2
    LDA M0
    STA M2
J2  LDA M2
    OUT
    HLT
M0  DAT
M1  DAT
M2  DAT
```

You can run the program here: [Max of 3 in LMC Emulator](http://paulhankin.github.io/lmc/lmc.html?program=ICAgIElOUAogICAgU1RBIE0wCiAgICBJTlAKICAgIFNUQSBNMQogICAgSU5QCiAgICBTVEEgTTIKCiAgICBTVUIgTTEKICAgIEJSUCBKMQogICAgTERBIE0xCiAgICBTVEEgTTIKSjEgIExEQSBNMgogICAgU1VCIE0wCiAgICBCUlAgSjIKICAgIExEQSBNMAogICAgU1RBIE0yCkoyICBMREEgTTIKICAgIE9VVAogICAgSExUCk0wICBEQVQKTTEgIERBVApNMiAgREFU&input=MjEzCjk4Nwo4OAo=)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've tried this and it works, thanks again!

Comment: @JanineHawkins perhaps accept the answer and upvote if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

A Little Man program that accepts three values as input and produces the largest of the three as output.

```
00  IN  901 Take first value as input 
01  STO 320 Store the first value in 20th mailbox
02  IN  901 Take second value as input 
03  STO 321 Store the second value in 21st mailbox 
04  IN  901 Take third value as input 
05  STO 322 Store the third value in 22nd mailbox
06  SUB 221 Subtract the second value (21st mailbox) from third value 
07  BRP 810 If the difference is positive then, move to the 10th instruction
08  LDA 521 As the second value is greater than third value, load second value
09  STO 322 Store the second value in 22nd mailbox
10  LDA 522 Load the value from 22nd mailbox
11  SUB 220 Subtract the first value (20th mailbox) from loaded value 
12  BRP 815 If the difference is positive then, go to the 15th instruction
13  LDA 520 As the first value is greater than loaded value, load first value
14  STO 322 Store the first value in 22nd mailbox
15  LDA 522 Load the value from 22nd mailbox
16  OUT 902 Output the loaded value
17  HLT 000 Stop
```

Answer (score -1):

LMC Assembly code   Comment

INP

L1   STA hi

L2   LDA co

```
 SUB two

 BRZ op

 LDA co

 ADD one

 STA co

 INP

 STA wo

 SUB hi

 BRP sw

 BRA L2
```

sw   LDA wo

```
 BRA L1
```

op   LDA hi

```
 OUT

 HLT
```

hi   DAT

co   DAT

wo   DAT

one  DAT 1

two  DAT 2

Input the first number

L1 Store the number as the highest so far

L2 Load the loop counter

Subtract two from the counter

If we are finished jump to output op

Otherwise load the counter

Add one to the counter

Store the updated counter

Get the next number

Store this as the working number

Subtract the highest number so far

Branch to sw(ap) if we have a new high

Otherwise branch back to L2

sw Load the working number (the new high)

Branch to L1

op Load the highest number again

Send it to output

Halt the program

Data  to hold the current high number

Data  to hold the loop counter

Data  to hold the working number

Data hold the loop increment number

Data the number of times to loop

This can easily be adapted for more numbers by changing the last DAT statement.
To do ten numbers, use 'two DAT 9' instead.

Comment: You have had more than a year to edit and format it better...